# Retrieve Users' Passwords SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-administration, password-hash

Is there a way to view the password of non-sysadmin accounts on SQL Server 2016?

I'm a database admin. I can simply change the password for the user, but I'd love to know if there is a way I can retrieve the password without resetting it.

Comment: No, passwords are never meant to be read by anyone.

Comment: Any good system will not only not allow you to read others' passwords, it will simply be impossible, because the password will be hashed. Theoretically you might be able to take the hash and construct a working match for it, but generally you cannot reverse the hash

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server user and login passwords are never stored; they are [hashed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  When a user logs in by presenting a password, that password is hashed and compared to the stored hash.